# If $A$ is $2\times 2$ skew orthogonal with $A^TA=-I$ and $\det A=1$ then $\operatorname{tr} A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is skew orthogonal if $A^TA=-I$ in $\mathbb{Z_p}$ for $p>2$. The general form of $2\times 2$ characteristic polynomial: $x²-(\operatorname{tr} A)x+\det A$. It is given: $\det A=\pm 1$

If $\det A=-1$ then $\operatorname{tr} A= 0,1,-1$. But if $\det A=1$, then $\operatorname{tr} A$ must be $0$ only. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: All, this is the seventh time this person has asked the same question using two different accounts. We won't tolerate such antics. Sorry about the inconvenience to those who tried to help them without knowing the history.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of it, I'm going to give a proof which is more matrix-oriented and more generalizable.

Since $AA^T=-I$, $-A^T$ is a right inverse of $A$, so it is the inverse of $A$, $A^{-1}=-A^T$.

Now, if $p(X)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ invertible of size $n\times n$, then
$$q(X):=\frac{X^n}{(-1)^n\det(A)}p(X^{-1})$$
is the characteristic polynomial of $A^{-1}$ (since it is monic, of degree $n$, and has $A^{-1}$ as root).

In our case, by hypothesis $\det(A)=1$, so $p(X)=X^2-$trace$(A)X+1$ and hence $$q(X)=X^2-\text{trace}(A)X+1,$$
what implies that trace$(A^{-1})=$trace$(A)$. But trace$(A^{-1})=$trace$(-A^T)=-$trace$(A)$, so
$$\text{trace}(A)=-\text{trace}(A)$$
and trace$(A)=0$ if there is no $2$-torsion.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited 27/01: As the OP has warned me privately, there was a mistake in a sign in the case $\det(A)=-1$. This makes a new type of solution to appear.**

This answer includes also the case with $\det(A)=-1$.

---

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A^T=\begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix}$ and
$$AA^T=\begin{pmatrix}a^2+b^2 & ac+bd \\ ac+bd & c^2+d^2\end{pmatrix}=-I,$$

**1)** If $\det(A)=1$ then we have the identities
$$\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2&=-1 & (1)\\
c^2+d^2&=-1 & (2)\\
ac+bd&=0 & (3)\\
ad-bc&=1 & (4)
\end{align*}$$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Multipying (3) by $c$ and (4) by $d$ we find $ac^2+bcd=0$, $ad^2-bcd=d$, so
$$ac^2+ad^2=d\implies a(c^2+d^2)=d\implies -a=d$$
by (2) and therefore trace$(A)=a+d=-d+d=0$.

Observe that this proof is valid over any commutative unital ring, we have not used that it is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in any way (nor that it is a field!).

**2)** If $\det(A)=-1$ then we have similar identities, changing (4) with $ad-bc=-1 \ (4')$. Then similar computations give us $a=d$ and $b=-c$.

Therefore $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}$$
with $a,b$ such that $a^2+b^2=-1$. Observe that this implies $AA^T=-I$, $\det(A)=-1$. Then trace$(A)=2a$, but this does not imply that trace$(A)\in\{-1,0,1\}$!

For example, we can pick $b=0$, $a^2=-1$. By quadratic reciprocity, such an $a$ exists in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p$ prime if and only if $p\equiv 1(\text{mod}4)$. We can pick for example $p=13$. Then $8^2\equiv -1(\text{mod}{13})$, so
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 0 \\ 0 & 8\end{pmatrix}$$
satisfifes the hypotheses in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ but trace$(A)\equiv 16\equiv 3\not\equiv 0,\pm1(\text{mod}13)$.

Similarly, in $\mathbb{C}$ we can pick $a=i$ to get trace$(A)=2i\neq 0,\pm 1$.

Comment: nice approach sir!

Comment: The most detailed answer ...

Answer (score 1):

For $\det(A)=1$, when we multiply both sides of the characteristic equation of $A$ by $A^T$, we get

$A^T(A^2-\text{tr}(A)A+\det(A)I)=0$

$A^TAA-\text{tr}(A)A^TA +A^T=0$

$-A+\text{tr}(A)I +A^T=0$

$ \text{tr}(A)I  =A-A^T$, but $\text{tr}(A-A^T)=0$ $\Rightarrow \text{tr}(A)=0$.

Comment: In the case when it's hard for you to see what is the trace of the final equation left side denote $tr(A)$  as scalar $t$. Now we have $tI=A-A^T$. Trace $tI=2t$ for dimension $2 \times 2$.

Comment: Perhaps you should add "when $p>2$", since tr$($tr$(A)I)=2$tr$(A)$.

Comment: @JoseBrox Thank you Jose for editing my answer. Regards.